# How do I use dynamic fields over all of the tables in a dataset in LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq, dataset

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I use dynamic fields in LINQ in the PART OF THE where query? I mean that I want to write `where x = *dynamic fields*`
2. I want to do the select query in all of the tables that are in the dataset, not on one datatable.

How can I do both of these things? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamic fields\files? Are you referring to columns added programmaticly, and not by code generator? What are the result you expect the query to return?

Comment: I mean that the compare fields are not static. they are dynamic.

Comment: I have a dataset that contain a few tables(datatables)/

Comment: i have a dateset that contain a few datatables and i want to see if one of the value colomn (by me its a key) appear in the other datatable? the value of the colomn is dynamic becuse i do this check on diffrent values. i hope that you understand me/ my english not well/ thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using [`Dynamic LINQ`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

### Example:

[image: Dynamic LINQ]

2. I suggest you use `LINQ to SQL`. If you still want to use `DataSet`s, using `Join()` operator might help. (Reference: http://forums.asp.net/p/1627101/4185000.aspx)